# IntelliJ is unable to query SQL Server database and returns an empty error message

Tags: sql-server, intellij-idea

I've run into an issue with IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.2, build #IU-201.7846.76 that I have no idea how to begin troubleshooting.

My SQL Server database is up and running just fine (our client applications and SQL Server Management Suite have no issues), but when I try to query it from within IntelliJ, I get no results and an error message that consists only of a period (.):

[image: screenshot]

The query itself does not matter as even this most basic of queries has the exact same result:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

Obviously, I am having a hard time finding a solution for something so vague by searching here or the web.

This is new behavior as of today; yesterday the queries were working just fine.

What does this error "message" mean and how can I determine the cause?

Comment: Please checkout https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-10839

Comment: @ScrappyCoco, looks about right! Thank you; will check it out. Though I'm not sure why there'd be an authentication driver issue showing up overnight without any updates.

Comment: The suggested workaround (updating the driver) did not work for me. I am on the same version of IntelliJ I used successfully yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a known issue in this version of the JetBrains Runtime, per https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-10839.

Updating the driver, as suggested, did not resolve the issue for me. Instead, rolling back to IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 worked out.